# Should I always use ConstraintLayout for everything?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

just a simple question, should we always use Constraint Layout for everything? why another layout still used today?

I want to make a simple login layout like this, should I use Linear Layout or Constraint Layout?

[image]

usually, I make every layout with Constraint Layout but my friend told me to use Linear Layout for the login, is it wrong if I use Constraint Layout? thanks before!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**ConstraintLayout** helps you to avoid using **nested layouts** and it causes **better performance**. it's not wrong to use it for everything but if you know that you are not going to have nested layouts, for example, three `Textview`s respectively, you can use **LinearLayout**. **ConstraintLayout** needs more XML code than **LinearLayout** for simple structures, and using **LinearLayout** is better for these situations.

Answer (score 3):

I would say ConstraintLayout is more versatile and has better performance compared to RelativeLayout, But LinearLayout has its own significance in android you can specify weights of view using LinearLayout and for complex UIs I would say going with ConstarintLayout is a better option because of its performance and in ConstarintLayout you can specify the view positions, heights, widths, margins and paddings based on screen sizes rather than hard coding the values to fixed dp

https://android.jlelse.eu/constraint-layout-performance-870e5f238100

The above link gives more overview of **LinearLayout** vs **ConsrainLayout** performances.

Answer (score 0):

No it it's depends on your need, if you want to make complex layout and want to make them responsive then you can.